# Error accessing files to attach in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, hudson, email-ext

I am using `Jenkins 1.552` configured with `email-ext 2.25` plugin.
My job should send an email with a file attached after each successful build. For that i am using the email plugin and i add the path of the the file i want to send in the attachment field.
The mail is sent successfully but the file is not attached and i have this specific error :

```
ERROR: Error accessing files to attach: remote file operation failed: /../hudson2/workspace/MY_JOB at hudson.remoting.Channel@host
```

What should be the cause of this access problem ?

PS : My job is running on a ssh slave.

Comment: Does that directory exist on the slave ?  It will be relative to the base directory that you set up in the slave configuration.  If it exists, does the Jenkins user have read access to it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will get the error because email-ext plugin uses ant script for attachment so it will only work with relative address.make sure your files to get attached should be under workspace of your job.

attachment pattern should be :**/foldername/*.txt (sample)

Comment: @philant thanks for fromating my answer hope this answer works

Comment: Email was triggered for: Success
Sending email for trigger: Success
ERROR: Error accessing files to attach: remote file operation failed: /Users/Jenkins/Desktop/DevOps_ios_build/workspace/DevOps_ios_build_new at hudson.remoting.Channel@4af3ea66:JNLP4-connect connection from 49.248.36.74/49.248.36.74:49254: java.io.IOException: Expecting Ant GLOB pattern, but saw '/Users/Jenkins/Desktop/DevOps_ios_build/workspace/DevOps_ios_build_new/build/IPA-PatientPortal/*.ipa'. See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html for syntax
Sending email to: ashish.karpe@compumatrice.comFinished: SUCCESS

Comment: I have given Path :   ${WORKSPACE}/build/IPA-PatientPortal/*.ipa

Comment: sorry it's :   build/IPA-PatientPortal/*.ipa

Comment: note : In my case jenkins master is ubuntu (aws ec2 instance) and slave is Mac laptop

Comment: Is this issue from from Mac Laptop ie Jenkins slave ? Is there some configuration required to send mail (ipa attachment) from Jenkins slave as I have send mail manually from slave it's sending successfully

Comment: Files in your workspace will be placed in the machine it was built, in this it might be your slave